# which port number is ml-gradle calling when performing a mlDeploy

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf, ml-gradle

Which is the port number is used by gradle internally while performing `mlDeploy`, `mlRelaodModules`, and `mlLoadModules` tasks in MarkLogic?

Answer (score 2):

The `mlDeploy`, `mlReloadModules`, and `mlLoadModules` tasks will use the configured ports for `mlRestPort` and `mlAppServicesPort`, depending upon the resource.

## [Ports used for loading modules](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/How-modules-are-loaded#ports-used-for-loading-modules)

> ml-gradle has to handle REST modules - options, transforms, services, and namespaces - differently from non-REST modules, as REST modules must be loaded via an app-specific REST server. However, not every MarkLogic app has a REST server. For this reason, ml-gradle takes the following approach by default:
>
> - Non-REST modules are loaded via the port defined by `mlAppServicesPort`, which defaults to 8000. This port is nearly guaranteed to exist in every ML cluster, making it a safe choice.
> - REST modules are loaded via the port defined by `mlRestPort`, which does not have a default value.
>
> See the [Property reference](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Property-reference) for all of the properties that are used for connecting to these ports.

Comment: Another thing to note is the `mlManagePort` property which defaults to 8002. This is the port used for configuring app servers and databases when running `mlDeploy`. To gain more insight on what is occurring, using the `--info` parameter will provide detailed information about the HTTP calls being made.