# mlLoadModules - connect timed out

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

I am getting `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` when running **mlLoadModules** to one ML Cluster in Azure, which is created from Marklogic Azure marketplace official image (**MarkLogic Multi-Model Database: Enterprise Edition v.10**).

Below is the error message.

[image]

I got the same error regardless of whether I put the host as any ML node or the cluster application gateway DNS (load balancer). I could see some files have been uploaded into the ML module DB.

I could run other ml gradle commends like mlDeployUser or mlReloadSchema etc.
(mlDeploy will fail with the same connection timed out error.)

Since I could run mlLoadModules and mlDeploy successfully to a single node ML in Azure created with **MarkLogic Multi-Model Database: Developer** v.10 official image, it is not about network speed or file size is too big etc.

How to resolve that issue?

```
 Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':mlLoadModules'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:188)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:174)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:402)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:389)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:382)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:368)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
Caused by: com.marklogic.client.MarkLogicIOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.sendRequestOnce(OkHttpServices.java:704)
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.putPostValueImpl(OkHttpServices.java:2905)
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.putValue(OkHttpServices.java:2826)
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.ServerConfigurationManagerImpl.writeConfiguration(ServerConfigurationManagerImpl.java:146)
        at com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.DefaultModulesLoader.loadProperties(DefaultModulesLoader.java:259)
        at com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.DefaultModulesLoader.loadModules(DefaultModulesLoader.java:174)
        at com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.DefaultModulesLoader.loadModules(DefaultModulesLoader.java:153)
        at com.marklogic.appdeployer.command.modules.LoadModulesCommand.loadModulesIntoTestServer(LoadModulesCommand.java:87)
        at com.marklogic.appdeployer.command.modules.LoadModulesCommand.execute(LoadModulesCommand.java:45)
        at com.marklogic.appdeployer.impl.AbstractAppDeployer.executeCommand(AbstractAppDeployer.java:101)
        at com.marklogic.appdeployer.impl.AbstractAppDeployer.deploy(AbstractAppDeployer.java:85)
        at com.marklogic.appdeployer.AppDeployer$deploy.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.marklogic.gradle.task.MarkLogicTask.deployWithCommands(MarkLogicTask.groovy:87)
        at com.marklogic.gradle.task.MarkLogicTask$deployWithCommands$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at com.marklogic.gradle.task.MarkLogicTask.deployWithCommandListProperty(MarkLogicTask.groovy:83)
        at com.marklogic.gradle.task.MarkLogicTask$deployWithCommandListProperty.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at com.marklogic.gradle.task.client.LoadModulesTask.loadModules(LoadModulesTask.groovy:10)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:502)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:487)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:470)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:106)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:271)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:249)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:89)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:60)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:180)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:105)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:85)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:42)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:114)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution$2.withWorkspace(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:284)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:174)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:402)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:389)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:382)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:368)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.kt:120)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.kt:283)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:195)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:249)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:108)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:76)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:245)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:96)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at com.burgstaller.okhttp.AuthenticationCacheInterceptor.intercept(AuthenticationCacheInterceptor.java:49)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:197)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:148)
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.sendRequestOnce(OkHttpServices.java:702)
        ... 138 more
```

Comment: Seems that the port you are trying to connect to isn't available. What is the configuration  and properties for appserver ports set to, and have you verified that they are all available (firewalls or anything in the way preventing comms)?

Comment: I think this issue is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69480883/which-port-number-is-ml-gradle-calling-when-performing-a-mldeploy).

After disable below two configuration lines in the gradle.properties file, 
```# mlRestPort=8030
# mlTestRestPort=8700```
I could load it to that 3 node cluster. 

Everything seems working correctly. But I still do not understand the use case for those two properties mlRestPort and mlTestRestPort. Are they used to auto-run some rest API calls to those ports via mlDeploy? May I have one sample use case?

Comment: My feeling is that the mlRestPort will be used by Gradle to rapid create a rest API server etc. Without it, one dedicated http-server.json file will need to be prepared in order to create a rest API server.

Comment: mlTestRestPort is used by marklogic-unit-test, but not sure if you are using that. mlRestPort triggers logic to deploy an extra default MarkLogic rest-api instance at the chosen port. You can also create one manually, works either way.

Comment: Regarding your original issue, I think Mads is right. It sounds like mlLoadModules is trying to reach a port that is unreachable. The stacktrace doesn't tell which port it tries to connect, but -i or -d might reveal that, allowing you to dig deeper into what goes wrong..

Comment: After setting up the appGateway and NetworkSecurityGroup for those custom REST ports, I could deploy to mlcluster in Azure. 

`mlNoRestServer=true` could disable mlgrade to create REST API. Hence I could manually create one under src/main/ml-config/servers folder.

**However, my question is what is the difference between these two approaches to creating RESTAPI servers? Advantage and disadvantage?**